# Point on a sphere - translating reference axis

Tags: geometry

I have a point on unit sphere described by two angles :

zr = Angle of rotation around the z-axis

zi = Angle of inclination from the z-axis

The problem that I have is that the data I need to use is described by two angles referenced to the x-axis. ie.

xr = Angle of rotation around the x-axis

zi = Angle of inclination from the x-axis

The way I've gone about doing the translation is this :

With reference to the z-axis any point on the sphere x,y,z can be described as :

x = cos(zr)sin(zi)

y = sin(zr)sin(zi)

z = cos(zi)

With reference to the x-axis any point on the sphere x,y,z can be described as :

x = cos(xi)

y = cos(xr)sin(xi)

z = sin(xr)sin(xi)

So using these equations with the different reference axes and translating x=x and z=z I get :

xi = acos ( cos(zr)sin(zi) )

xr = asin ( cos(zi) / sin(xi) )

The problem I have is that this last equation has a divide by zero in it for xi=0 which suggests to me that I've probably got something wrong somewhere as I don't think this can be right. If someone can point out to me where I've gone wrong I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are doing ok so far. Remember that if $xi=0$ then $zi=\frac{\pi}{2}$, so both $\cos zi$ and $\sin xi$ are 0.

But what are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to produce software to plot something, for example. If so, there are probably better algorithms.

Comment: Thanks, I'd just spotted that case with xi=0 so I could avoid the divide by zero. Yes, I am writing software to plot loudspeaker data. Ironically it turns out that the data I'm using is that used as an illustration on the "Spherical coordinate system" page on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Bosch_36W_column_loudspeaker_polar_pattern.png If you look closely at the points in the polar plots you can see that they rotate around the x-axis (aka the "on-axis" direction of the loudspeaker). But all my coordinate geometry is standard spherical coordinates, hence my problem.